# Isn't it too fast for an ASP.NET page to download in 0 ms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, caching, asp.net-development-serv

I'm currently measuring the time spent to load a web page from a C# program.

The Visual Studio solution has a console program and an ASP.NET website with just one page. The website is hosted on ASP.NET Development Server. The console application queries the web page like this:

```
bool isSuccess;

Stopwatch timeSpentToDownloadPage = Stopwatch.StartNew();

WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:12345/Test.aspx", UriKind.Absolute));

request.Timeout = 200;

using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
    string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    isSuccess = (responseText == "Hello World");
}

timeSpentToDownloadPage.Stop();
```

The web page has nothing special, just a response on load and no ASP.NET code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

Now, the stopwatch shows every time that the code spent 0 ms. to do all the work (querying the server, getting the response, etc.).

How is it possible? Isn't there something wrong with what I'm doing? Really, I expected at least 10-20 ms. to execute all client-side code, then 100 ms. to:

- [client side] Find the page to query from uri (which does not require DNS query, so it's quite fast),
- [client side] Do the request,
- [server side] Initialize ASP.NET engine,
- [server side] Process the request,
- [server side] Find and read .aspx file and execute compiled code (at least reading file may cost several ms.),
- [server side] Build response, including headers, then send it,
- [client side] Receive the response and process it (trim).

So why is it so extremely fast? Is there a tricky cache which just skips all/most of the steps and return "Hello World" to the client?

If there is a "hidden" cache, where is it and how can I disable it to measure the "real" time spent?

Comment: How are you examing the stopwatch returned value? Are you examining the ElapsedMilliseconds property? You could always put a sleep in the code to test that this is working correctly. Just because it's on localhost doesn't mean it can call the page, wait for it it be rendered and check the response in sub 1 millisecond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes this can and must be 0 ms!** Because your server is on a `localhost`. Try to get ASP.NET server somewhere else in a world wide network.

And you don't resolving localhost because this is a constant address to `127.0.0.1`.
And communication to this address is operated only by the your OS kernel.

Comment: Ok, there are neither DNS lookups, no slow tasks related to networking. But what about ASP.NET engine? Does it really read the .aspx file? Does it execute code-behind? I thought that even reading a one-byte file will cost a few milliseconds.

Comment: I hope ASP.NET doesn't take 2 ms/file. Because that would mean it can't handle more than 500 requests per second. I expect all small files to be cached.

Comment: Ok, I found it. I apologize, it was a stupid error in my code which resulted in 0 ms. result. What do you suggest? Do I close the question, or leave it and accept the first answer? BTW, now that the time is measured correctly, it gives 1.1 s., which is quite awful. On the other hand, it is because I'm in debug mode, so stepping into ASP.NET code may be very long for the debugger.